# createjs tween location based off of current location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, createjs, tween

I am using `create.js`'s `tween.js`. I am trying to make a bounce animation, more complex than the one given. More specifically, I am trying to tween an objects's `y` by an offset rather than a given coordinate. It seems like there is a simple way of doing this like:

```
createjs.Tween.get(circle, {loop:false}).to({offset-x: 100}, 1000, createjs.Ease.linea);
```

**Ultimate Question:** How do I tween the coordinates of an object based off of its current position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a Tween instance, you are creating a deterministic animation, meaning that you can set the position of the tween to any value (between 0 and 1), and it will be where you expect it.

If I understand what you are asking, you want to make a tween up-front, but have it use the object's current position instead of the value it was at when the tween was made. If this is the case, then you will need a different approach. Perhaps you should generate the tween on-demand when it is needed, rather than initially. That way, it could use your current position.

Here is a quick sample: http://jsfiddle.net/x4xxwjuv/
The ball moves at a constant rate, but when you click the buttons, it will:

1. Tween back a bit, based on its current position
2. OR Tween to a specific Y position (fall to the floor)

Then it resumes moving normally. The tweened ball is filled, the animated one is not.

Here is sample code from the spike.

```
createjs.Tween.get(ball)
    .to({x: ball.x+(ball.xSpeed*-4), y:ball.y+(ball.ySpeed*-4)}, 1000, createjs.Ease.bounceOut);
```